# C# remove parenthesis from string

Tags: c#, regex, parentheses

This seems to be a common question for C# users and after research and multiple attempts I cant for the life of me remove a pair of parenthesis from a string. The string I am having a problem with is `Service (additional)`.

After doing my research I understand parenthesis are treated differently in `Regex.Replace`. With my research also came multiple answers that I attempted but nothing seems to have worked. Here are some ways that I have tried to remove these parenthesis.

```
cleanValue = Regex.Replace(intVal, " ", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(",", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "");

cleanValue = Regex.Replace(intVal, " ", "").Replace(@"\(", "").Replace(@"\)", "").Replace(",", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "");

cleanValue = Regex.Replace(intVal, " ", "").Replace("[()]", "").Replace(",", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "");

cleanValue = Regex.Replace(intVal, " ", "").Replace(@"[^a-zA-Z]", "").Replace(",", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "");
```

None of these worked, after stepping through the code I just see the the space between the 'e' and '(' removed. Am I missing something?

In case anyone wanted to see the `function` that is being used here it is:

```
    public static string CleanExtra(string intVal)
    {
        string cleanValue;
        if (intVal == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Value cannot be null", "original");
        }
        else
        {
            //cleanValue = Regex.Replace(intVal, " ", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(",", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "");
            //cleanValue = Regex.Replace(intVal, " ", "").Replace(@"\(", "").Replace(@"\)", "").Replace(",", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "");
            //cleanValue = Regex.Replace(intVal, " ", "").Replace("[()]", "").Replace(",", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "");
            cleanValue = Regex.Replace(intVal, " ", "").Replace(@"[^a-zA-Z]", "").Replace(",", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "");
        }

        return cleanValue;
    }
```

Comment: Why would you use Regex for that? Can't you use string.Replace()?

Comment: It was just the first way to remove something I stumbled upong. I'll try string replace for the time being but regardless this should also be an option.

Comment: Regex are meant to search for patterns, like decimal characters, uppercased letters, something that looks like an email address or a phone number, etc. If you happen to know exactly which character or string you want to replace, string.Replace is a far better choice, performance-wise.

Comment: Okay thanks for taking the time to explain the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After your call to `Regex.Replace(...)` you're actually using `string.Replace(...)`. This makes your call to `.Replace(@"[^a-zA-Z]", "")` useless.

Simplify it instead to:

```
cleanValue = Regex.Replace(intVal, @"[^a-zA-Z]", "");
```

This should remove all spaces and special characters which is what it looks like your code is trying to do. This includes parentheses.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 23):

A Regex is overkill here as this can be done with a simple `Replace` call:

```
string val = intVal.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "");
```

Comment: I have a question if you dont mind. From the comments in this question people have been saying that after my initial `Regex.Replace(...)`, the `.Replace` that follows is equal to `string.replace`. If thats the case (if this I am not mistaken), why wouldnt this work in the first place:

cleanValue = Regex.Replace(intVal, " ", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(",", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("-", "");

Comment: Okay thats odd that it didnt, maybe it was another error I encountered. Thank you for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 3):

That is because every second `Replace` is a call on a `string` and therefore doesn't replace with regex.

Comment: So youre saying that if the first replace is removing the parenthesis, they just come back when I do the second replace in the regex?

Comment: The `Regex.Replace` returns a `string`. When calling `Replace` there is no regex involved like in your first call (that is why you called `Regex.Replace` in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want a fancy LINQ way to do it, instead of regex, here you go:

```
return new string(input.Where(c => c != '(' && c != ')').ToArray());
```

And this will remove all kinds of parentheses or brackets:

```
var chars = input
    .Where(c => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.OpenPunctuation
                && CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.ClosePunctuation)
    .ToArray();
return new string(chars);
```